# poll?transport=longPolling&connectionToken=AQAA.... in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: jquery, asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am in Visual Studio 2015 (debug mode) and I see that the following call is performed repeatedly, (I never noticed this in Visual Studio 2012)

[image]

upon opening it, I see that it is related jquery,

[image]

When I searched online I see that this has been discussed since Visual Studio 2013.

How can I stop this repeated call? and what will be the impact after stopping...?

Any guidance / suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a browser link feature of visual studio. If you make any changes to your mark up logic in visual studio and save it you don't need to hit Ctrl + F5 in your browser to see the changes it is automatically picked up by browser. Under the hood it uses Signal R. You can look for details at http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link